# Why is mongoose calling my validator with an empty string when my default array is empty?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I've added this line to my schema...

```
recentTags: {type:[String], default: [], validate: tagRegex}
```

And this is my tag validation regex...

```
tagRegex: /^[a-z0-9#]+( *[a-z0-9\\/:\-()[\].?#]+)*$/
```

Note: it doesn't allow an empty string, nor should it as that is not a valid tag name.

So my problem is this, all my tests that touch that schema now fail with this Mongo error...

```
ValidationError: User validation failed: recentTags: Validator failed for path `recentTags` with value ``
```

I don't get why it's trying to run my validator at all, why would it do that when the array of values is empty? And why is it passing it an empty string?

Note I've been careful to rebuild my test db and wait for all the indexing to finish before running my tests and the rest of them work fine. My Mongo version is 3.6.8 and my Mongoose version is ^5.9.25, all running on node v14.11.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the validator is applying the regex to the entire string array as a whole, with an implicit type conversion to a string when applying the regex; an empty array will be implicitly type converted to the empty string `""`.

---

### A Possible Solution

From my understanding, it appears you are after validating *each* individual element in the array, as opposed to the entire array value. An array type can be more complexly specified with an element-level validator.

Here is an example of the change:

```js
const Tags = model("tags", new Schema(
    {
        recentTags: {
            type: [{
                type: String,
                validate: tagRegex,
            }],
            default: [],
        },
    },
));
```

Here are some examples of insertion with this validation:

```
// valid, uses the default value
await Tags.insertMany([{}]);
// also valid, no elements are here so no validation is done
await Tags.insertMany([{recentTags: []}])
// also valid, the element passes the regex
await Tags.insertMany([{recentTags: ["test"]}])

// not valid, the element does not pass the regex
await Tags.insertMany([{recentTags: [""]}])
```

See the documentation on array schema types: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

---

### Side Notes

You might also desire to validate that [`recentTags` is in fact an array](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_5.html#array-required) or use [more complex custom validation error messages](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#custom-validators).

Comment: Yes that did the trick. Thanks for the great, clear explanation and the side notes. I really appreciate your help!